# I want to join two table using find_in_set

Tags: php, mysql

1) **student_table**

```
 student_id  student_name
 100         yash
 101         rahul
 102         jay
 103         roy
```

2) **stop_table**

```
stop    student_id
abc     100,102
def     101,103
```

This is my request

```
SELECT
  student_table.student_name,
  stop_table.stop           
  FROM student_table
  JOIN stop_table ON 
  FIND_IN_SET(student_table.student_id,'101,102')
```

It is not giving stop of that particular `student_id
result =>`

```
rahul abc
rahul def
jay   abc 
jay   def
```

Comment: Let me know the result u want to get.

Comment: i should have to get student_name with respect to his stop

Comment: like rahul->def and jay->abc

Comment: your fiddle solved my problem thanx for helping me out

Comment: @tushar If my answer did solve your problem please mark it accepted (the green check mark under the up/down vote arrows). Marking answers accepted makes them more useful to other users who may be searching for a similar solution and has the benefit of giving you 2 rep points as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `JOIN` condition doesn't make any sense as it doesn't restrict the selection of values from `stop_table` relative to those from `student_table`, so you are essentially getting a `CROSS JOIN` between `student_table` and `stop_table`. That is why you are getting multiple rows for each student. What you actually need is to `JOIN` on

```
FIND_IN_SET(student_table.student_id, stop_table.student_id)
```

and put your `JOIN` condition in as a `WHERE` condition to select only students with ids 101 & 102:

```
SELECT s.student_name, t.stop
FROM student_table s
JOIN stop_table t ON FIND_IN_SET(s.student_id, t.student_id)
WHERE s.student_id IN (101, 102)
```

Output:

```
student_name    stop
rahul           def
jay             abc
```

Note I've written the `WHERE` clause slightly differently but it could be written as

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(s.student_id, '101,102')
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6bf76239828e1f5c558df47d2bc8f283)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  student_table.student_name,
  stop_table.stop           
  FROM student_table
  JOIN stop_table ON 
  FIND_IN_SET(student_table.student_id, stop_table.student_id)
```